# Strange cursor behavior with inline images

Tags: inline-image

When I try to type something right before an inline image, it inserts only one character there, and the cursor somehow moves to the end of that image link. When I try to type "foo" it goes like this ("_" is the cursor):

```
_[image] 
f_[image] 
f[image]_
f[image]o_
f[image]oo_
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What major-mode are you using to display inline images, and how about providing us with a sample version of your code [to display the inline image] so that we can all try to reproduce your working example?  Does it look like this, for example?:  `[[/path/to/my/local/image/file.jpg]]`  Or, is there some other form that we should use to reproduce the issue?  Do you have any minor-modes that are potentially causing the conflict like word-completion libraries -- company, etc.?  Have you tried a minimal working example with **Emacs -Q** and does the problem go away in that circumstance?

Comment: It's org-mode. I have (setq org-startup-with-inline-images t) and (run-with-idle-timer 1 0 'org-display-inline-images). I'm not using company in org-mode. It's GUI Emacs for OS X. The problem didn't go away even when I deleted everything except a couple of lines that are related to loading the org-mode package and restarted emacs.

Comment: I am able to confirm the behavior you describe, and I was able to eliminate the idle timer from the equation.  All I needed to do was type `M-x org-toggle-inline-images` in an `org-mode` buffer.  I don't have a solution . . . sorry.